# How to calculate charge on an internal and external surface of a conductor, due to an internal charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, gauss-law

Having a bit of trouble with a question our first year lecturer has given us to think about.

Say we're given a hollow cylinder (the hollow region is central and spherical), made of a conducting material. The initial charge of the cylinder is -2.1mC. If I place a charge in the centre of the spherical hollow, with charge 2.3mC, what is the charge on the surface of the internal spherical hollow, and on the external surface of the cylinder?

I'm guessing we have to use newton's superb theorem, and or the fact that the field inside a conductor is zero, but we're not given detail about the shape and size of the cylinder/spherical hollow so I'm not quite sure how to apply this. (There's probably something really obvious that I'm missing)

For reference here's a pic of our set up:

[image: Hollowed out cylinder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that the field inside a conductor is zero, you can apply Gauss' Law for flux to say that any spherical surface lying inside the conductor cannot have any flux through it, so that the enclosed charge is zero.  Therefore, you need -2.3mC of charge from the conductor on the inner surface to make sure that the enclosed charge is zero.

For the external surface, you know that all charge of a conductor has to be on the surface, so the sum charge on the external and internal surfaces has to be the total charge on the conductor.